# argument substitution - typescript xpath method

Tags: typescript, xpath, parameter-passing

I have the below method I'm trying to pass two strings to. But my checkbox variable isn't getting passed because it is a double quoted string. How do I pass that value ?

```
 checkSelectorbox(card: string, checkbox: string) {
        const select = element(by.cssContainingText('mat-card-title', card))
        .element(by.xpath('//div[contains(text(), "checkbox")]'));
      select.click();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `'//div[contains(text(), "' + checkbox + '")]'`?

Comment: That was it. You are a lifesaver :)